# How can I allow access from a single IP in a range, while disallowing the rest, and allowing all other addresses at the same time in httpd.conf?

Tags: apache, httpd.conf

I'm trying to allow one address of an entire subnet to access the directory while forbidding the rest, and also allowing all other addresses to access the directory

Would I have to break those commands down into separate blocks like;

```
<Directory directory-path>   
    <RequireAny>
    <RequireAll>
       Require ip 126.26.110.1
    </RequireAll>
    <RequireAll>
       Require all granted
       Require not ip 126.26.110.0
    </RequireAll>
    </RequireAny>
<Directory>
```

I just want to make sure I'm on the right track and would really appreciate some feedback

Answer (score 0):

Interesting case. Assuming what you mean is to disallow the whole subnet but that ip, but allow any other subnet.

RequireAny is implied so you should not specify it unless necessary.

I think you should go for (worked for me in my tests):

```
<Directory /path/to/whatever>
       Require ip 126.26.110.1
       <RequireAll>
           Require not ip 126.26.110
           Require all granted
       </RequireAll>
</Directory>
```

This way it is either the first choice or the second group of choices rounded by requireall.